# select all comments of specific posts mongoid 2 rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

Lets say an author has many posts, and a post has many comments.
How could you select all of the comments of a specific authors specific few posts?

Use case: I want every recent comment of an author's posts with the tag 'rails'

```
@author = Author.find(params[:author_id])
@posts = @author.posts.where(:tag => 'rails')
```

now

```
@comments = @posts.?????.where(:created_at.gte = 1.month.ago)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this via `@posts.?????`

You should grab post ids and select comments

```
post_ids = @author.posts.where(:tag => 'rails').map(&:id)
# In rails >= 3.2.1 you can use pluck(:id) instead of map(&:id)

@comments = Comment.where(:post_id => post_ids, :created_at.gte = 1.month.ago)
```

**upd:** or

```
@posts = @author.posts.where(:tag => 'rails')
@comments = Comment.where(:post_id => @posts.map(&:id), :created_at.gte = 1.month.ago)
```

Comment: Could you shorten it to: Comment.where(:post_id => @posts.map(&:id))